# SwiftUI : Apply different animation style for Button using enum(s)?

Tags: swift, enums, swiftui

I have a ForEach loop that displays all of the Buttons with icons from enum Icons. Every time I tap a button it will stay active until I tap another button ( same animation for every button case ).
[image]

```
enum Icons: String,CaseIterable, Hashable {
    case overlayText = "Text"
    case image = "Image"
    case rotate = "Rotate"
    case audio = "Audio"
    case merge = "Merge"
    case split = "Split"
    case duplicate = "Duplicate"
    case none
}

struct EffectPanel: View {
    @State var currentIconSelected: Icons = .none
    @State var listIcons = [Bool](repeating: false, count: Icons.allCases.count)
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(Icons.allCases, id: \.self) { i in
                        if i != .none {
                            EffectIcon(icon: Icons(rawValue: i.rawValue)!, currentIconSelected: $currentIconSelected)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to add a second animation style for 3 selected buttons, for example for the cases "rotate, audio, merge". Right now, I manually apply the second animation style to the case "rotate" by  using

```
if currentIconSelected.rawValue == "Rotate"
```

this is my EffectIcon View:

```
struct EffectIcon: View {
    
    var icon: Icons = .none
    @Binding var currentIconSelected: Icons
    
    var isSelected: Bool {
        if icon == currentIconSelected { return true}
        return false
    }
    
    @State var buttonFlash: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0){
            Button(action: {
                self.currentIconSelected = self.icon
            }){
                ZStack {
                    if isSelected {
                  // ---- begin manually applying animation ---- //
                        if currentIconSelected.rawValue == "Rotate" {
                            HStack {
                                if buttonFlash {
                                    Image("\(Icons.allCases[1].rawValue)")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .frame(width: 65, height: 70)
                                    
                                } else {
                                    Image("\(Icons.allCases[1].rawValue)Active")
                                        .font(.title2)
                                        .frame(width: 65, height: 70)
                                }
                            }
                            .onTapGesture {
                                self.colorChange()
                            }
                 // ---- end manually applying animation ---- //
                        } else {
                            Image("\(icon.rawValue)Active")
                                .font(.title2)
                                .frame(width: 65, height: 70)
                            Text("\(icon.rawValue)")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .font(.system(size: 12))
                                .foregroundColor(Color("orange"))
                                .frame(alignment: .leading)
                                .lineLimit(1)
                                .padding(.top, 56)
                        }
                    } else {
                        Image("\(icon.rawValue)")
                            .font(.title2)
                            .frame(width: 65, height: 70)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func colorChange() {
        self.buttonFlash.toggle()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(Int(0.1)), execute: {
            withAnimation(.easeIn){
                self.buttonFlash.toggle()
            }
        })
    }
}
```

I know there are better ways to implement ( using another enum + init... ) but I have not figured it out yet.
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: We don't have access to you images (Image("\(Icons.allCases[1].rawValue)Active")) so it's hard to tell what you're trying to do here. What's the difference between the regular and Active icons? What is the end goal here? You want a button that constantly flashes when you tap it?

Comment: Hi @nicksarno, I just added an image of my button to my post. For the origin animation, the regular icons will stay white until it gets tapped and changes to the active icon with color orange. My end goal is I could have a second animation for selected buttons ( flash once when I tap it ) the remaining button stay with the origin animation. I hope this makes sense for you. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started the right path. I don't have your custom icons, so I just used a systemIcon for the example.

Notes:

- In SwiftUI it's extremely powerful to use [ternary operators](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/3/7/the-ternary-operator) to manage the state of a view. This way, for example, you only need to write out Image() and set its font/frame/etc. one time. They basically let you write "**If true do x otherwise do y."**
- By setting an image's renderingMode to Template, you can change it's color (if it's a compatible format)
- I added a bunch of comments within the code too. Your question talked about adding a 'second animation'. In SwiftUI you can basically animate as many modifiers as you want to add multiple animations to a view.
- I used a .onTapGesture() instead of a Button(). It's just a personal preference for this use case, but you can change it back if you prefer.

Code:

```
enum Icons: String,CaseIterable, Hashable {
    case overlayText = "Text"
    case image = "Image"
    case rotate = "Rotate"
    case audio = "Audio"
    case merge = "Merge"
    case split = "Split"
    case duplicate = "Duplicate"
    case none
}

struct EffectPanel: View {
    @State var currentIconSelected: Icons = .none
    @State var listIcons = [Bool](repeating: false, count: Icons.allCases.count)
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(Icons.allCases, id: \.self) { icon in
                        if icon != .none {
                            // You are looping on the icon already
                            // Don't need to init a new Icon()
                            EffectIcon2(icon: icon, currentIconSelected: $currentIconSelected)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .background(Color.black)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct EffectIcon2: View {
    
    var icon: Icons
    @Binding var currentIconSelected: Icons
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName:
                currentIconSelected == icon ?
                "heart.fill" : // selected image
                "heart" // not selected image
            )
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .font(.title2)
            .frame(width: 65, height: 70)
            // animate color when selected
            .foregroundColor(
                icon == currentIconSelected ? .orange : .white
            )
            // animate opacity for .audio
            .opacity(
                (icon == .audio && icon == currentIconSelected) ?
                0.1 :
                1.0
            )
            // animate rotation for .rotate
            .rotationEffect(
                Angle(degrees:
                        (icon == .rotate && icon == currentIconSelected) ?
                        360 :
                        0
                    )
            )
            // animate scale for .merge
            .scaleEffect(
                (icon == .merge && icon == currentIconSelected) ?
                1.5 :
                1.0
            )
            // When icon is selected, Animation is set to .repeatForever
            // When not selected, Animation returns to .default
            // Autoreverses set to false for .rotate animation only (optional)
            // - You can change .linear(duration) for different animation timing
            // - You can remove .repeatForever(autoreverses) for only 1 loop
            .animation(
                currentIconSelected == icon ?
                Animation.linear(duration: 1.0)
                    .repeatForever(autoreverses: (icon == .rotate) ? false : true) :
                .default
            )
            // Add a background layer with the Text
            // This is similar to a ZStack (a matter of coding preference)
            // The order which you add modifers is important in SwiftUI
            // By adding .background after the .animation, it will NOT animate with the previous
            // Like ZStack, Background layers have alignment abilities (currently .bottom)
            // Animate opacity so that Text only appears when selected
            .background(
                Text("\(icon.rawValue)")
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .opacity(
                        icon == currentIconSelected ?
                        1.0 :
                        0.0
                    )
                    .padding(.bottom, 4)
                    .animation(.easeInOut)
                
                , alignment: .bottom
            )
            .onTapGesture {
                currentIconSelected = icon
            }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Your solution solved my problem. God bless you and have a great holiday Nick!!